# How can I use existing chapter select functionality in AngularJS/Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently writing a new Ionic/AngularJS app against an existing PHP backend and database.  Currently the api/database has HTML documents stored in the database which then have fields replaced by customer data much the way standard reporting tools do it (it could also be described as a mail merge).  They also have used # Anchor tags to describe chapters and have a select/option dropdown for a quick jump to different chapters.  All of the chapter options are in a separate field from the document itself.

Problem: AngularJS removes the Anchor and Option tags when populating the content and chapter dropdown via ng-bind-html.  I need to figure out how to process this on the front end if possible because changing the back end is going to be costly in both time and money.

Example 1: Partial HTML Text in the Javascript Object before ng-bind-html

```html
<h3><a id="1"></a>PRE-EMPLOYMENT</h3>
<p><strong>The Application Process:</strong></p>
<p><strong>The application process is the initial opportunity to avoid individuals prone to workplace violence and terror activities. Employers often overlook this opportunity to prevent problems. Look for discrepancies, individuals with poor employment histories often fabricate information on their applications. Be cautious of:</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&bull; Gaps in employment.</p>
<p>&ndash; Potential problem employees often leave with no substitute employment.</p>
<p>&ndash; Gaps in employment are often explained with, &ldquo;I could not find a job,&rdquo; or a similar statement.</p>
```

Example 2: Content in web page after using ng-bind-html:

```html
<h3><a></a>PRE-EMPLOYMENT</h3>
<p><strong>The Application Process:</strong></p>
<p><strong>The application process is the initial opportunity to avoid individuals prone to workplace violence and terror activities. Employers often overlook this opportunity to prevent problems. Look for discrepancies, individuals with poor employment histories often fabricate information on their applications. Be cautious of:</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>• Gaps in employment.</p>
<p>– Potential problem employees often leave with no substitute employment.</p>
```

Notice the id in the anchor block has been removed in the text.  I have researched a number of things here and have not yet found a solution to this issue.  The discovery of the removal came as we were implementing the select dropdown for the chapters where AngularJS removes all of the  tags from the existing chapter dropdown as shown in examples 3 and 4.

Example 3: Object Data for Table of Contents

```html
<option value="#1">Pre-Employment</option>
<option value="#2">The Interview Process</option>
<option value="#3">Drug Testing</option>
<option value="#4">Violence Prevention Program</option>
<option value="#5">Responsible Person</option>
<option value="#6">Crisis Team</option>
```

Example 4: Processed Data from ng-bind-html

```html
Pre-Employment
The Interview Process
Drug Testing
Violence Prevention Program
Responsible Person
Crisis Team
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add an Angular Filter for "unsafe".

```
.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
  return function(val) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
  };
})
```

This allowed me to filter the ng-data-bind-html as truly unsafe html.

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="documentDetail.Content | unsafe"></div>
```